# Inconsistencies between SAP Host Agent command outputs based on version?

Tags: sap-basis, netweaver

I am running the following saphostctrl command to look over my SAP NetWeaver application landscape:
`/usr/sap/hostctrl/exe/saphostctrl -function GetCIMObject -enuminstances SAPInstance`

This provides the following output:

```
*********************************************************
 CreationClassName , String , SAPInstance
 SID , String , AWS
 SystemNumber , String , 00
 InstanceName , String , ASCS00
 InstanceType , String , Central Services Instance
 Hostname , String , ip-80-0-0-126
 FullQualifiedHostname , String , ip-80-0-0-126.ec2.internal
 IPAddress , String , 80.0.0.126
 Features , String[] sep=| , MESSAGESERVER|ENQUE
 SapVersionInfo , String , 753, patch 1000, changelist 2119750
```

But, when I run in another application, I see a similar output, but with the field `InstanceType` missing.

I checked the sap host agent version in the instance that emitted `InstanceType`, and see:

```
--------------------
SAPHOSTAGENT information
--------------------

kernel release                721

kernel make variant           721_REL

compiled on                   Linux GNU SLES-9 x86_64 cc4.1.2  for linuxx86_64

compiled for                  64 BIT

compilation mode              Non-Unicode

compile time                  Oct 10 2020 05:55:38

patch number                  49

latest change number          2026611
```

In the case that `InstanceType` is missing, this is the version info:

```
--------------------
SAPHOSTAGENT information
--------------------

kernel release                721

kernel make variant           721_REL

compiled on                   Linux GNU SLES-9 x86_64 cc4.1.2  for linuxx86_64

compiled for                  64 BIT

compilation mode              Non-Unicode

compile time                  May 21 2016 14:02:28

patch number                  15

latest change number          1674266
```

Is there a change between patch number 15 and 49 that adds instance type?

I tried looking through the [SAP Host Agent Change Log](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP%20Host%20Agent/8661d17ee5c047a887f686b33e990ede/8337374dc12c4fd6beec4e9eedbec417.html) but was unable to find any info related to this specific command.